# Set line weight for all series in pivot chart

Tags: excel, charts, pivot-table, excel-2000

I've tried looking around all the chart options, but I can't seem to find a way to set the line width of the chart series once and for all. Of course, I could run a macro every time the series selection in the pivot chart is changed, but I'm hoping there's a simpler way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the current (slow, hacky) solution - A "CustomChart" class module:

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents customChart As Chart

Private Sub customChart_Calculate()
    Dim customSeries As series
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each customSeries In customChart.SeriesCollection
        customSeries.Border.Weight = xlThick
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

and this snippet at the top of any module:

```
Dim myChart As New customChart

Sub Auto_Open()
    Set myChart.customChart = Charts(1)
End Sub
```